# Moving between tabs in aspx with save function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have a page with 5 tabs on it, containing fields that the user fills out. I would like to save the data from each tab as the user navigates between tabs (postback). What is the best way to do this? I have tried javascript (no postback here) and using a case statement triggered by a case statement. In the second method, for some reason the navigation does not occur and the data is cleared on the button click.

Method 1:

```
$(function () {
            $("#<%= btnBack.ClientID%>").css("display", "none");
            $("#<%= btnNext.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
                $("#tabIncident").tabs("option", "active", $("#tabIncident .ui-tabs-active").index() + 1);
                //event.preventDefault();
            });

            $("#<%= btnBack.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
                $("#tabIncident").tabs("option", "active", $("#tabIncident .ui-tabs-active").index() - 1);
                //event.preventDefault();
            });
```

Method 2:

protected void SaveEventDetails(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isSubmitted = false;
            PageLocation pageLocation = (PageLocation)Session["pageLocation"];

```
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "BACK":
                if (_eventID == 0)
                {
                    Save(false, Mode.Edit, Status.Save);
                    RedirectTo(pageLocation - 1);
                }
                else
                    Update(_eventID, false, Status.Save);
                    RedirectTo(pageLocation - 1);
                break;
            case "NEXT":
                if (_eventID == 0)
                {
                    Save(false, Mode.Edit, Status.Save);
                    RedirectTo(pageLocation + 1);
                }
                else
                    Update(_eventID, false, Status.Save);
                RedirectTo(pageLocation + 1);
                break;
```

Comment: i think there's a built in control for this, i forget the name right now. is it possible to use that?

Comment: it's called a 'MultiView'.

Comment: Don't use server side post back. You jquery ajax to send your data on each click of tab.